# Making an application in android 2.2 version compatible with android 3.0

Tags: android-3.0-honeycomb, android

I have an application written in Android 2.2 version. Now I want to make this app compatible in all tablets.

I went through the link [Optimizing apps for 3.0](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html)

As per the details mentioned, I created folders: `drawable-xhdpi`(for storing images) and `layout-xlarge` and `layout-xlarge-land` to keep the layouts.

Added `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>` in manifest too.

But when I ran the app, the drawables are not taken from my xhdpi folder. So images getting displayed are too small. What may be the reason for this? Should I have to add anything more? Also whether this xhdpi and xlarge folders will help me out for all types of tablets(i.e. tablets with different screen sizes)?

Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what tablet are you testing on?

Comment: currently on samsung galaxy tab 10.1

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7634971/535915) by anujprashar:

> ... For 10.1 tab you should use drawable-xlarge folder ...

Compared to that answer, I didn't add `<supports-screens>` and it works on my galaxy tab, also works for Nook color (cm7).