# Drawables are always read from mdpi folder, regardless of screen size

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I am trying to create an application that works both on Samsung galaxy tab GT P1000 and samsung galaxy tab 10.1; The samsung galaxy tab 10.1 (1280 * 800) has a much bigger screen than that of the GT P1000, so I am assuming the GT P1000 should read from hdpi, and 10.1 should read from xhdpi. The surprise is that both of them are reading from the mdpi folder. Regards

Comment: have u added this line in your android manifest file : <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Large screen size does not necessarily means high pixel density. For pixel density you have to consider both physical screen size and screen resolution.

For example consider `Galaxy Note 1` and `Galaxy Tab 10.1`, both have screen resolution of `1280*800` but galaxy tab 10.1 has physical screen size of `10.1 inch` whereas galaxy note has physical screen size of `5.3 inch`, which is almost half of galaxy tab size. Thus galaxy note has more pixel per inch than galaxy tab 10.1 and it has `xhdpi` density, where as galaxy tab 10.1 has `mdpi` density, check density values in this link-

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For 10.1 tab you should use `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` folder and GT P1000 should also use mdpi but as I have seen on many online posts that GT P1000 has problem, it has mdpi density but it uses drawables from hdpi, I have not checked myself so for GT P1000 you can try to use `drawable-large-hdpi` folder, if `drawable-large-mdpi` does not wok.

And also add xlarge support in your manifest.

```
                  <supports-screens       
                  android:smallScreens="true" 
                  android:normalScreens="true" 
                  android:largeScreens="true" 
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  />
```

You have to use 2.3 and above sdk for using xlarge as it was added later.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that Galaxy 10.1 is actually mdpi not hdpi or xhdpi!

Comment: I created a `drawable-w820dp` folder for my Galaxy 10.1 drawables (for consistency, as I already had a `values-w820dp` folder) and it worked fine - the Galaxy 10.1 no longer takes its drawables from the `mdpi` folder.

Answer (score 1):

`mdpi` refers to the screen density, in dots per inch, not the overall size. I presume that both devices have similar densities, so they load resources from the `mdpi` folder.

You can have separate layout resources based on the actual screen size (large/medium/small) rather than the density. Refer to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: I think you are right, but that should I do in this case, since the design is awfully scrambled between the two, and using dp unit doesn't help in this case :S

Answer (score 0):

Just Make new folder name drawable-xlarge-mdpi and paste all images in it..  Device will automatically get from that folder..!

My problem with Galaxy Tab2 was solved!